# Sequence and derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: I \rightarrow R$ differentiable and $a \in I$ such that's :

$$ \forall (x_n),(y_n) \in I, x_n \neq y_n, x_n \rightarrow a, y_n \rightarrow a \rightarrow lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n} = f'(a) $$

Prove that $f'$ is continuous.

I have taken  $z_n \rightarrow a$ but I cant prove that 
$f '(z_n)$ converges for $f' (a)$. Thanks for read, exists another post but the solution I do not understand

Comment: Yes sorry, I edit

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions is not even well posed.  There is no conditions on $x_n$ and $y_n$ just that they are different?  That is not good enough for the slope of the secant line joining $(x_n,f(x_n))$ to $(y_n,f(y_n))$ to approach $f'(a)$.